# Multiple Apple devices/One Bluetooth speaker

Tags: macbook-pro, bluetooth, speakers

I have my iPhone synced to a Bose bluetooth speaker.  I would like to sync my MacBook Pro to the same speaker.  When I open "Bluetooth" on the Mac, there are no options to add another device, and I'm getting a spinning wheel.  I have just restarted the Mac, but that didn't help.  How do I do this?

Comment: You probably have to press the bluetooth button for a while on the Bose speaker to let it become available for pairing

Comment: Thank you, Edd - that was exactly the problem!   You're awesome for responding!

Comment: You're very welcome ! You can accept the answer to close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press the bluetooth button for a while on the Bose speaker to let it become available for pairing, then it will appear in the bluetooth folder of your Mac.